# sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: One or more mappers failed to initialize

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

On trying to insert a new record in SqlLiteDb using SQLAlchemy through:

```
user_1=User(username='First User',userEmail='first@email.com',password='password')
```

I am getting following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: One or more mappers failed to initialize - can't proceed with initialization of other mappers. Triggering mapper: 'mapped class User->user'. Original exception was: When initializing mapper mapped class User->user, expression 'Post' failed to locate a name ('Post'). If this is a class name, consider adding this relationship() to the <class 'flaskblog.User'> class after both dependent classes have been defined.
```

```
class User(flaskDb.Model):
    id = flaskDb.Column(flaskDb.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = flaskDb.Column(flaskDb.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    userEmail = flaskDb.Column(flaskDb.String(
        120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = flaskDb.Column(flaskDb.String(20), nullable=False)
    image_file = flaskDb.Column(flaskDb.String(
        20), nullable=False, default="default.jpg")
    posts = flaskDb.relationship('Post', backref="author", lazy=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"User('{self.username}','{self.userEmail}','{self.image_file}')"


class Post(flaskDb.Model):
    id = flaskDb.Column(flaskDb.Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    title = flaskDb.Column(flaskDb.String(25), nullable=False)
    content = flaskDb.Column(flaskDb.Text, nullable=False)
    datePosted = flaskDb.Column(
        flaskDb.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    user_id = flaskDb.Column(
        flaskDb.Integer, flaskDb.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Post('{self.title}','{self.datePosted}','{self.title}')"
```

What can I try next?

Comment: Doesn't SQLAlchemy change the tablename of the class to lower case? I.e. should your relationship in your `User` model be `'post'` not `'Post'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You re having a circular dependency error.

Instead of putting the posts in the Sser.

```
posts = flaskDb.relationship('Post', backref="author", lazy=True)
```

Remove it and put this on the Posts instead.

```
user = flaskDb.relationship('User', backref="posts", lazy=True)
```

You can still access user via:

```
usera = User.query.get(1)
usera.posts
```